# SQL Inner Join and a Repeater

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, repeater, inner-join

I have a database with three tables: questions, tags, and questions_tags. This is how they are setup:

```
---------
questions
---------
Question_ID
Question_Title
Content

----
tags
----
Tag_ID
Tag_Title

--------------
questions_tags
--------------
Question_ID
Tag_ID
```

In my program, I am using a repeater to display the Question_Title, and Content. I want to be able to have the Tag_Title being repeated (with however many tags there are for a certain question as well.

Essentially, I am trying to re-create something similar to that of stackoverflow's question blocks (with the question, tags, views, etc.).

So let's say I have a Question with 5 tags. That question gets inserted into the questions table, along with an ID (auto increment) and the content of the question. Then, with any tag the user attached to the question, those tags would be put into the tags table with an associated ID. Then the questions_tags table would match up the Question_ID and Tag_ID. So it could be something like:

```
Question_ID | Tag_ID
    1       |    3
    1       |    4
```

So question 1 has 2 two tags in this example.
So how can I have the repeater repeat each question in the questions table, and then repeat each tag associated with that question?

I have created a view thus far which inner joins questions, tags, and questions_tags, but repeating it just repeats a question more than once...

Here is what I had done for the join:

```
SELECT q.Question_ID, qt.Tag_ID, t.Tag_Title, q.Question_Title, q.Content, q.Views
FROM questions q
INNER JOIN questions_tags qt
ON q.Question_ID = qt.Question_ID
Inner JOIN tags t
ON qt.Tag_ID = t.Tag_ID
```

Or, in other words, how could I create a view with my joins such that it creates the table like this?:

```
Question_ID | Tag1 | Tag2 | Tag1_Title | Tag2_Title | Question_Title | Content
```

Comment: so u basically want to create a view?

Comment: Yes, a view setup like the one at the end of my post, so I can easily repeat it with my repeater.

Comment: You can't really create a view like this since there is no guarantee that you are going to have the same number of tags, and thus the same number of columns, per question. I don't use repeaters in my apps, so I can't answer specifically about how to do this with repeaters, but the way that I would approach it would be to load the data into a structured class hierarchy (question contains collection of tags), then render that hierarchy as needed (i.e. render the tags separately).

Comment: @competent_tech or perhaps there is a limit to the number of views that he requires such as max of 5 tags then create the view depending on this assumption..?

Comment: I could limit the tags such as JackyBoi as suggested...But I'm not sure if I would want the tags to be a fixed number. Currently I'm thinking of setting up a couple classes - a Questions class and a Tags class. A Question would have an id, title, content, and an Arraylist of tags. a Tag would have an Id and a title. Then possibly make a List of Questions and set the list as the data source of my repeater? Not sure if that made sense, haha but thanks for the suggestions guys.

Comment: @JackyBoi: I had thought of that as a possible solution, but if that is the case, the best approach would be to add tags1-5 to the question instead of storing them in a separate table. If you don't do this, you end up with a very messy query and you would probably have to store a question-unique sort order in the questions_tags table in order to ensure that you get the right information.

Comment: @adback03: Yes, that is exactly what I would do. Except I would use a generic list instead of arraylist (i.e. List<Tag>), in case you need to serialize it down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after review all the various suggestions, I have decided to go with competent_tech's answer of loading the data into a structured class hierarchy. I have made a class for questions and tags, and one of the parameters for the questions class is a list of tags. By going this route, I have avoided needing to create any views, and am able to use the tables initially stated in my question.

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from you question is that you are attempting to flatten relationship between question and tag. If you are using mysql (assumming that as you have tagged your question with mysql), then you can use mysql's [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function. Something like the following should give you what you are looking for.

```
SELECT q.Question_ID, q.Question_Title, GROUP_CONCAT(t.Tag_Title SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'Tags'
FROM questions q
INNER JOIN questions_tags qt
ON q.Question_ID = qt.Question_ID
INNER JOIN tags t
ON qt.Tag_ID = t.Tag_ID
GROUP BY q.Question_ID, q.q.Question_Title
```

Output should look something like the following:

```
id     title    tags
1      quest1   tag1, tag2, tag3
2      myquest  anotherTag, anotherTag2
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you lose the Tag_IDs from the result, which are probably needed if they provide a hyperlink to a definition of the tag or a tooltip on hover.

Comment: @competent_tech and that's the issue, I need that Tag_ID so I can use it in the link.

Comment: You change the formatting that suits the need. If it needs to be a link, it can be generated within the sql with something like: GROUP_CONCAT(Concat('http....',t.Tag_ID,'...',Tag_Title)...)

Comment: Sorry for the typo above. What I was trying to say is you can generate the full URL (if needed the HTML <a> tag aswell) by formatting the string.